# I can't find Global Undo in Blender 2.8

Tags: interface, customization

I can't turn off/on Global Undo in Blender 2.8 because I cant see the checkbox in the User Preferences dialog.

[image: Editing Tab Blender Preferences]

Answer (score 3):

Not that place but in `System` panel:

[image]